# jQuery not allowing to set an attribute as 'selected'

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.3.2 and I am running into exactly the same [problem mentioned here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2902a4393f93df52?pli=1).

```
 var tmp = jQuery(selector_string);
 tmp.attr("selected", "selected");
```

I am getting value of tmp correctly in IE6. However setting the attribute to 'selected' is failing. It works in IE7 and in Firefox.

Another person [having the same problem](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/05/jquery-ie6-and-could-not-set-selected.html).

Comment: `tmp.val(data_selected)` returns the value of the `tmp` element. You cannot chain the `attr()` function on it.

Comment: @artlung I quoted the wrong code. It has been edited. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to verify without IE6, but perhaps `val()` could be changed to `value === ''`?  Not sure if that is compatible.

Also, perhaps `.attr("selected", true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the DOM element you're trying to set is a dropdwon? Or another element that can indeed be 'selected'?

Comment: Yes the DOM element is a dropdown value and the DOM is properly selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success when dealing with dropboxes like this in IE6 with just setting the `selectedIndex` property on the parent `select` element, rather than trying to tell an individual option to be "selected".

```
$('select#mySelector')[0].selectedIndex = 3; // or whatever
```

You could determine an individual `option`'s index by just counting his prev siblings

```
var si = $('option#myOption).prevAll('option').length;
```

It was interesting to see in the second link you included, that a solution was given suggesting you inject a slight delay between manipulating the DOM and trying to do what you want. I'm guessing IE6's rendering/javascript engine must rely on the element being visible on the page before allowing this action. (The settimeout would allow this occur.)

Good luck!